# Query Rewrite in Wordpress - Remove query string in custom pages

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a custom page in Wordpress which presents different data based on the query string. So my query string right now looks something like

```
http://example.com/extcat/?uid=15&src=blog
```

Now this is not getting picked either by Google's spidering software or by tracking software properly. They are all tracking it as one single page

```
http://example.com/extcat
```

without the uid.

What I want is to rewrite the above query in a format like one of these

```
http://example.com/extcat/uid/15/src/blog
http://example.com/extcat/15/blog
http://example.com/extcat/15/?src=blog
http://example.com/extcat/15/
```

I don't care which format I use.

I tried using .htaccess and the WordPress api both. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Try go to Settings -> Permalink -> ( mark: Post name or Numeric or Custom Structure.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I tidied up the presentation, and added the [mod-rewrite] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an in-depth article on how to accomplish what you are doing.  Basically, you'll need to register your custom query variables so WP can do it's magic using `add_rewrite_rule()`.  It's a long article, but will provide a better answer then I can write.  Plus, you'll learn a whole lot!

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/building-customized-urls-wordpress/